# Problem adding reference of C++ dll in C# project

Tags: c#, c++, cplex

I implemented a C++ dll that compiled successfully.  The project contains a header and cpp file.  The cpp file includes several third party headers (Cplex mainly).

Once the dll was created:
I then attempted to reference the dll in visual studio and it didn't work.
In the console application, I used the tlbimp.exe and I encountered the error message:

```
<AssemblyFileName.dll> is not a valid type library.
```

I then used dependency walker and it showed the error message:

```
"MSVCR90.DLL was not found".
```

**I am surely missing something and would appreciate if you can point what the solution could be?**

Comment: Regarding the MSVCR90.dll - I think that needs to be present in the same directory as the .exe for your project, but I am not sure if this is related to your first error message. I googled it, and managed to download it.

Comment: @BeeBand - I don't think MSVCR90.dll needs to be present in the same directory if the redistributable is installed. Because the redistributable will copy the dll's into system32 directory.

Comment: redistributable is installed yet the error is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here, one is that not all native dlls are also type libraries, only COM ones.

the second error is more like you do not have a Visual C++ runtime available, are you building the C++ dll on the same box of trying to use it?

for non COMN dlls, instead of import the type library you could use DLLImport approach.

Comment: I am building C++ project in the same machine.  Also the dll was previously an .exe so I think the C++ runtime is available.  Is it just a matter of adding DllImport attribute and specifying name of the dll as its argument?  Do I need to place the Dll in the bin folder of the project?

Comment: I added the dll in the bin directory of the project.  Then used DLLImport with dll name. I got the error message "Unable to load DLL 'MyAssemblyName.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Answer (score 0):

If you donot have Visual Studio 2008 you will get the error MSVCR90.dll. You can just install the Visual Studio 2008 runtime and then you will not have any dependecy errors related to MSVCR90.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9b2da534-3e03-4391-8a4d-074b9f2bc1bf&displaylang=en